# Parsing json from Anyobject in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am uploading image with `SRWebClient` library in swift.

**My code:**

```
func uploadImage() {
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePicture.image, 100)
    SRWebClient.POST("url")
        .data(imageData, fieldName:"imagefile", data: ["username":self.username,"key":self.token])
        .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
            println("result: \(response)")
            //I have to parse result variable in here
            },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in

        })
}
```

Actually it works well. I am returning json from my server and I want to parse it. But I couldn't find how to parse json from `AnyObject` ?

**This code's ouput:**

```
{"status":1,"picture":"e8ca745f511e8104fe2f920aab5d09c6.jpg"}
```

How can I parse this json in `response` variable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let json = response as? [String : AnyObject] {
    for key in json.keys {
        if let intValue = json[key] as? Int {
            // json[key] is an Int. Do something with intValue
        } else if let stringValue = json[key] as? String {
            // json[key] is a String. Do something with stringValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you breakpoint in code where response has that json in it, what class does the debugging console say response is?

Comment: Please look at this: http://prntscr.com/7a47ss and this: http://prntscr.com/7a480s

Comment: I mean to look specifically in the Variables View in the Debug Area. It will have `response` in bold letters, and beside it in light gray text it will say what class of object it is. What is that class?

Comment: Could you look at this https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient#json-deserialize I tried this code but I am getting: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1036f2c50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1036f38d0).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the lib you are using and you can see, from **line 216 - 221** in [SRWebClient](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift) that the JSON serialization is done for you:

```
let json:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(result!, options: nil, error: &error)
                    if (error != nil && failure != nil) {
                        failure!(error)
                    } else if (json != nil && success != nil) {
                        success!(json, httpResponse!.statusCode)
                    }
```

So **success** is called with an already parsed JSON object. Try to cast it to a dictionary like this:

```
if let jsonResponse = response as? [String: AnyObject] {
  // do whatever needs to be done with the dictionary here
}
```

And the **status** passed is a [HTTP Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: It means that the response object does not have a "status" key. I wrote my answer strictly to your code's output

Comment: Please look at this: http://prntscr.com/7a4444 and output: http://prntscr.com/7a44fa

Comment: No, I added "upload ok" section in println. You can see in first screenshot.

Comment: I tried like this: http://prntscr.com/7a4hfa but it is not writing "parsed" to console.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any error? What kind of value does the **status** variable has?

Comment: No  I am not getting any error. status variable returning 200.

Comment: I couldn't understand, jsonResponse variable is looking nil.

Comment: Alright. So let's look at the backend here. You say you yourself are returning a response. Are you sure you are returning a **JSON** rather than a normal **String**?

Comment: OK. I'm out of options here. Hopefully you didn't just copy paste the output in the validator... Are you using **PHP** as backend language? Could you show the line that is responsible for creating the **JSON**?

Comment: Could you look at this https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient#json-deserialize I tried this code but I am getting: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1036f2c50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1036f38d0).

Comment: It means that the object you are trying to cast is not a **NSDictionary** but is an **NSString**. I've commented about this a couple of hours ago. I do not think that the mistake lies in your client code, but in your backend. Is there a simple **GET** request which I could call against your backend?

Comment: I can't do that because I am uploading image file.